# How do I determine pages printed by each user in office?

Tags: microsoft-office, printing

We are working in a small office and using Xerox ColorQube 9303. We have a team of 20 persons who are using same printer. How do I get a report of pages printed by each user?

Answer (score 2):

Your printer's documentation is available at this link
http://download.support.xerox.com/pub/docs/CQ930X/userdocs/any-os/en_GB/sys_admin_guide_us-en.pdf

If you refer to pg79 you will find instructions on creating an audit log.

If you refer to pg157 you will find instructions on creating user accounts with quotas for better control.